# Does Android-Beacon-Library support extended advertisement packets from Bluetooth5?

Tags: android, beacon, altbeacon, ibeacon-android

I'm trying to implement an app using advertising BLE-Beacons in a similar way the existing automated contact-tracing apps do. But I need more than the normal 25 free bytes in the beacon layout.

Since Bluetooth 5 there should be the possibility to use extended advertisements with up to 255Bytes packet size (as described here: https://www.novelbits.io/bluetooth-5-advertisements/)

I've seen the extra-data-field, but it just supports long and I couldnt find documentation about it and if it really is what I'm searching.

So is there an option to use extended advertisements or do I need to implement it from scratch? If the extra-data-field is for extended advertisements it should be possible to transfer my data into bytes, then into long and do it backwards when reading it out, isnt it?

Thanks really much for your help

Sanny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Android 8+ SDKs supports extended BLE 5.0 advertising packets with `BluetoothDevice.PHY_LE_2M`, this will only work on devices with both hardware support and firmware drivers with 5.0 extensions.

The Android Beacon Library does not have any tools that allow advertising beacon packets or scanning beacon packets with extended lengths.  The reasons are:

- Relatively few phone models have firmware support for BLE 5.0 extensions.
- No commonly used beacon formats use these extended packets.

That said, the library is extensible and can be augmented to offer these features for supported devices.  If you can make a good case for adding these features and are interested in helping do the work, you may wish to open a feature request issue or proposed implementation pull request against the open source repo.

Comment: Thank for the detailed answer!
Would love to see the lib managing to do these features but never did something in a project like that and just got ~1month left for my bachelor thesis. So I think it would be more feasible for me to "just make it work" for myself and then contributing it to the library in a more organized way when I've got time for that.

Is there another way than trying isLeExtendedAdvertisingSupported() at the specific smartphone to find out if it supports extendedAdvertising? Tried to find it for the one my institute bought but couldnt find more than "supports Bluetooth 5"

Comment: You have to make the `isLeExtendedAdvertisingSupported`  call, yes, but also look for errors on scanning and advertising API calls.  You will probably not have success with cheaper models from Chinese OEMs.  Your best bet would be from newer Pixel devices.

Comment: Tested it right after posting my comment and it works for the GalaxyA12s my Institute bought this year. 
So for later: the feature request issue and/or possibility to help with the implementation are on git isnt it? Sorry but like I said, never did something like that before and my bachelor was pretty theoretic with just really few practical coding parts in it.
So maybe I will need some explanation then on how to work together on this and in which standards you want to have the work/documentation.

Comment: The best approach is to write up the details about what you want the library to do  (do you want it to just advertise larger packets or both advertise and detect?)  Showing an example of what the beacon packet would look like as opposed to existing standard beacon packets the library supports like AltBeacon, iBeacon and Eddystone.  And if detection is needed, would the existing APIs (e.g. ranging, monitoring) work as-is for what you want to do or would you need them to change.  Use the link [here](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/new) to create a new issue.